# How to test in bash one or two conditions

Tags: bash, if-statement

I need to test if a variable is not something or something else:

```
a="6" ; if [ "$a" != "6" ] || [ "$a" != "4" ] ; then echo "ok" ; fi
```

returns: ok

I just don't get it... ?!!

Comment: [Read the `test` manual page.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) The information you want is early in the page.

Comment: You're using or; 6 != 4, so the second part is true, making the whole statement true.

Comment: @Evert is correct. The logical test you actually want is ``!("$a" == "6" || "$a" == "4")``. or'ing not-equals is *not* the same as not'ing the combination of or'd equals. You could also do ``"$a" != "6" && "$a" != "4"``, which is logically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if [ "$a" != "6" -o "$a" != "4" ] ...
```

But it doesn't make sense as this condition is always true ($a can't be 4 and 6 at the same time). You might want `and` instead:

```
if [ "$a" != "6" -a "$a" != "4" ] ...
```

Comment: `-o` and `-a` are all but deprecated. Use `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` and `[ ... ] && [ ... ]`, respectively.

Comment: you'd need [[ condition1 operator condition2 ]]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that `$a` is *neither* 6 nor 4, use

```
if [ "$a" != 6 ] && [ "$a" != 4 ]; then
    echo "a is neither 6 nor 4"
else
    ....
fi
```

or

```
if [ "$a" = 6 ] || [ "$a" = 4 ]; then
    echo "a is either 6 or 4"
else
   ....
fi
```

For this particular case (two single-digit numbers), pattern matching is shorter:

```
if [[ $a != [46] ]]; then
    echo "a is neither 4 nor 6"
fi
```